# UWP hosted web app launch native view

Tags: uwp

I have an UWP app which can play .ism/Manifest videos when url is provided and also can download if needed.

I have a webapp which i want to create as a hosted UWP app so that when clicked on play redirects view to native view and plays the video.

Could someone point me out to some tutorial or any reference in this context.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

For launching your UWP application from your web app you need to :

1. **Create a custom uri scheme for your application.**

   What this will do is that once the system identifies your application's unique uri scheme it will launch your application.

   [Tutorial on how to create a custom uri scheme for your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/automate-launching-uwp-apps)

   With the uri you can pass parameters (in your case the url for the .ism). You need to handle the logic in the `OnActivated` event handler of your application and play the video.

   [Handle URI Activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation)
2. **Add code in your web app to launch  your app-specific uri.**

   Tutorial here : [Link](http://michaelcrump.net/open-edge-from-chrome-link/)

Hope this helps..

Comment: Yes, i have a C# app which opens using custom URI and plays the video. But now as the hosted web app(React App) is JS App how do i open the videoplayer view when i click a custom URI from the hosted web app?

Comment: Have you overridden your application OnActivated event ? If yes, then you just need to hit your URI from your JS code..(which I have mentioned in the 2nd point). I am not sure about React but in pure js you may do it like this `window.location("myapplication://single-player/level3?godmode=1&ammo=200"); ` and it would open your application with the given parameters ..